# Splitting matrix input in Python

Tags: list, matrix, python-2.x

I would like to get the input of a 5x5 matrix in a way like this:
(input could even be strings)

```
12345
67894
12345 
65431
```

i.e getting 5 elements/ line.

So I've chosen the below method in python:

```
for i in range(5):
    j = 0
    a[i][j], a[i][j+1], a[i][j+2], a[i][j+3], a[i][j+4] = raw_input()
```

Now the problem is that I wasn't able to get the matrix input, if the n value becomes 3, 7 etc any other than 5, Since I've declared like this

```
a[i][j], a[i][j+1], a[i][j+2], a[i][j+3], a[i][j+4] = raw_input()
```

Please someone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer you to use numpy if you are going to play with matrix operations.

```
from numpy  import *

def create_matrix(no_rows):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(no_rows):
        row = raw_input("Enter row no "+str(i)+" values:")
        matrix.append(tuple(row))
    print array(matrix)

create_matrix(5)
```

output:

```
Enter row no 0 values:12345
Enter row no 1 values:12345
Enter row no 2 values:12345
Enter row no 3 values:12345
Enter row no 4 values:12345
[['1' '2' '3' '4' '5']
 ['1' '2' '3' '4' '5']
 ['1' '2' '3' '4' '5']
 ['1' '2' '3' '4' '5']
 ['1' '2' '3' '4' '5']]
```

Answer (score 1):

make the dimension `n` a variable, and use `map` to convert your input strings to a list of numbers:

```
In [6]: n=5
   ...: a=[]
   ...: for i in range(n):
   ...:     a.append(map(int, raw_input()))
   ...:     

12345

67890

76543

23456

13579

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 [7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

**Note** that the code above doesn't limit your 2D array a n*n square matrix. If your input is:

```
1234

2235

23452346

1234132

1
```

you'll get:

```
In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 2, 3, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2],
 [1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider validating your input.

```
def get_matrix(rows=5, columns=5):
  matrix =[]
  for i in xrange(rows):
    row = raw_input()
    assert(len(row) == columns)
    matrix.append(row)
  return matrix
```

usage:

```
>>> get_matrix(1,2)
34
['34']
>>> get_matrix(2,2)
33
45
['33', '45']
>>> get_matrix(2,2)
145
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in get_matrix
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing us 4x5 matrix in your question and asking solution for 5x5 matrix. If you're trying to input a 5x5 matrix using lists, You should be careful about Bound Checkings. You've to declare the whole list before you index them. I've tried this and it worked.

```
a = [
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0]
]
for i in range(5):
    j = 0
    a[i][j], a[i][j+1], a[i][j+2], a[i][j+3], a[i][j+4] = input()
```